# Issue with double quotes in String interpolation with strftime, in older ruby/rails installs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, strftime

I use RVM and have a few different ruby versions, mostly for different rails apps but not always.  I'm using `ruby-1.8.6-p420` for an older rails app and have a strange issue with using double quotes as a call to strftime, inside a String interpolation block.  eg

```
irb(main)> puts "time = #{Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"
time = 16/06/2014
=> nil
irb(main)> Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
=> "16/06/2014"
irb(main)> puts "time = #{Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}"
irb(main)/
```

At the end, when i use double-quotes inside the `#{}` block, the forward slash is basically waiting for input.  I need to CTRL&C to cancel out of it and get back to the active irb console input.

If i try this in `ruby-1.8.7-p302` i get the same problem, but if i try it in `ruby-1.9.3-p194` then there's no problem: it works fine.

I don't think this is RVM related because i get the same problem on the production server which has `ruby-1.8.6-p420` installed natively without using RVM.

If i use code like this in my rails app, then it works fine (ie renders out into html fine or whatever).  The problem just seems to occur in irb and the rails console.  So it's more of an irritant than anything else: it sometimes stops me pasting chunks of code from my codebase into the console.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: I think its because `puts` returns nothing so it is returning `nil`. but it prints what is written in it for example first output `time = 16/06/2014`

Comment: That doesn't explain why `puts "time = #{Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"` is different from `puts "time = #{Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}"` though.  The first one works, the second one hangs.

Comment: second one hang because of syntax of string interpolation. string is interpolated by this "#{variables}". so in between these quotes if you  place another quote then string interpolation will break. to use a string within interpolation use single quotes like "#{' string '}"

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not true.  This works fine:  `puts "foobar = #{"baz" << "qux"}"`: this puts `foobar = bazqux
` and returns nil, as expected.  I can only replicate this problem when using strftime with double quotes inside the `#{}` block.  Any other string manipulation i do works fine whether it's single or double quotes.